# How to (cheaply) measure power usage of a 250V socket

Tags: power, cost

My air conditioner runs off a socket providing 250V, 15A. I'd like to figure out how much power it's using in a cheap way, so I can budget how long to run it.

Ideally, I'd be able to plug in something like a $25 Kill A Watt. But no, that's 120V-only. Everything else is just damned expensive (I may as well run the aircon all month instead of paying $200 for The Energy Detective...).

Is there anything I can do? Looking at the electric meter isn't an option, I don't have easy access to it in my apartment block.

Comment: There are countless energy meters on the market, ranging from sub-$10 to thousands of dollars. Almost every DIY shop will have one or two models on the shelves, often of the very cheap kind (but perfectly usable to get a pretty good idea of power usage)

Comment: "Ideally, I'd be able to plug in something like a $25 Kill A Watt. But no, that's 120V-only. Everything else is just damned expensive"

Comment: Is the outlet single phase? If so there are many cheap monitors that will work fine. Otherwise some current clamps and an Arduino (using Emonlib) would get you a cheap monitor.

Comment: I'm a layman. How do I know if the outlet is single phase? Can you give me an example of a cheap monitor that I could safely plug into this 250V socket? I've searched tirelessly with no luck.

Comment: 240V outlets in most residential areas in the united states is provided by tying together two opposing phases or sometimes if you are lucky you have a true 3-phase connection, the phase-neutral voltage is still 120V, you can wire a kill-a-watt or other 120V meter from phase to neutral, and using a little bit of math calculate your total load.

Comment: @Archeus - current clamps sense current by measuring the induced magnetic field around the conductor carrying it (ex: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005), you will still need to figure out the actual electrical configuration in order to compute the true power (3-phase, vs 2-phase, vs single phase at 240) since a clamp will only give you current on the leg it is clamped to.

Comment: So... you are in the US, but you have a 230VAC outlet? Well, order a power meter from outside of the US then!

Comment: @user36129 many appliances in the U.S. use 240V, most homes get two (sometimes 3) phases at 120V. Most outlets are wired single phase (phase-neutral-(ground)) but this makes it easy to get a 240V socket where you need it (phase-phase-(ground) or phase-phase-phase- (ground) depending on the actual appliance).

Comment: I have no practical experience but I understand physics; presumably n-phase means n signals out of phase with each other by 1/n, 2/n, 3/n etc. of a cycle? Surely it's single phase by the time it hits the socket in my apartment or I'd have more than three pins, right? I'm between the socket and the appliance so I can just pretend it's single phase (right? Genuinely figuring this out as I go).

Note, 250V isn't a typo. It really says that on the socket. The aircon has 230/208V written inside it. I guess it knows how to deal with the different voltage?

Still confused re what measuring device.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you are, but you can get inexpensive surplus watthour meters on eBay etc. They will give you true power (not VA). [This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/120v-or-240v-Itron-CENTRON-Electronic-Electric-WATTHOUR-METER-House-Sub-Metering-/181440178683?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a3ead69fb) is a CENTRON Itron one that's available for about $20.

[image]

Comment: I like the look (and price) of that thing. What do I have to do to plug it into this? 

![250v socket](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6127955/junk/250v.jpg)

Also, what is the difference between watts and "true power"?

Comment: Watts are true power. VA are Volts \$\times\$ Amps, which is will give you different answer, in general (VA \$\ge\$ W). There are four big tabs on the back, it would have to be mounted in a box and wires attached to the tabs (in and out).

Comment: Okay; in my world W = VA. I've just read about apparent power and understand more.

Comment: If the load is a heater or something resistive like an incandescent bulb then W=VA but if it's electronic or a motor, then they won't be the same. For residential applications the power company charges only for W (times hours, of course, for energy), in every case I've seen.